# How can I enable another user to renew a Microsoft Office small business subscription at $99 per year?

Tags: microsoft-office, license, subscription

I have added a friend as a non-privileged user of my small business license, and she has expressed interest in being able to renew the subscription.

What can I do so that she will receive any renewal notice, and be capable of keeping the subscription current? Will that happen if I convert her account to an administrative account?

Thanks,

Comment: "Will that happen if I convert her account to an administrative account?" - She will have complete control over your subscrption and could take ownership of it.  Wouldn't it be easier fro your friend to just get their own subscription?  Since Microsoft doesn't support split payments, she would be paying the entire $99 no matter what.

Comment: Yes you can turn her user into an administrative account, and as Ramhoud points out, she'll gets lots of rights that way. It depends on how well you trust her. Alternatively, you could setup her user as administrator temporarily, then let her change the subscription to a creditcard she owns, then remove her admin rights. Alternatively, allow her to come to you (or you to her) and login yourself, then make het add the creditcard details while you are not watching, then logout. Another option is that you pay for the subscription and let her send money to you.